# What information can I find about a build from the assembly info?

Tags: c#, build-process, assemblies, clr

Following on from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971476/how-do-i-find-the-current-time-and-date-at-compilation-time-in-net-c-applicatio), what useful information can you retrieve from a .net assembly about the build process?  I know I can look at the [AssemblyVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute(VS.80).aspx) to get major and minor application version, and when the build took place.

Can I find:

- Who did the build? i.e. user name.
- On what machine?
- Which O/S version?
- Anything else useful?

Answer (score 0):

From my (limited) investigations (into assemblies I've built) you're basically limited to what the author put into the file.

About the only thing that's automatically assigned are the "Internal Name", "Original File name" and "Language".

There might be some IDE's that put in the information you require, but by default Visual Studio isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

By default, you don't have any of that information. Jon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971476/how-do-i-find-the-current-time-and-date-at-compilation-time-in-net-c-applicatio/971499#971499) to your previous question is actually the correct way to do this. You want to create custom attributes for each piece of information you want (or one attribute with properties for each) that apply to an assembly. This is how the attributes typically found in your AssemblyInfo file work.