# What is the best way to implement versioning of a binary?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, versioning

I am thinking of the following design:

```
static class AppVersion
{
     public static string BuildDate 
     {
       get; set;
     }
     public static string Version 
     {
       get; set;
     }
     public static string GetVersion 
     {
       get; set;
     }
}
```

A few questions on this:

1. How can I get the build date?
2. How can I print a date in a nice format?
3. How can I obtain and print the Visual Studio version in a nice format?
4. It is probably a bad idea to hard code the version into the binary, so I put the version into assembly information. How can I programmatically get it?

Comment: Rich, do me a favor and leave my posts alone?

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175256/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-assembly-versioning-attributes

... and ...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199823/best-practices-for-assembly-naming-and-versioning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your first questions are a matter of taste. You could use [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx) to get any style you want. Regarding your last question:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Version
```

returns the version number of the current assembly and:

```
typeof(SomeTypeInSomeAssembly).Assembly.Version
```

will return the version number of the assembly containing the specific type.

Answer (score 1):

For build Date look at 
http://dotnetfreak.co.uk/blog/archive/2004/07/08/determining-the-build-date-of-an-assembly.aspx

For the version / Get Version look at the System.Reflection.Assembly name space.

As for printing the date in a nice format, you'll want to either use the extension methods built off of DateTime class such as .ToShortDateString() or CultureInfo.

Answer (score 1):

We run all our production builds through CruiseControl.NET, which (among many other things) has the facility to version builds.

We then have a snippet of code that applies the CC.NET-generated build number (and other stuff) to AssemblyInfo.cs just before it's given to the compiler for building.

I suppose you could use a similar technique to insert the build date into a constant in some class somewhere in your app.

Answer (score 0):

For build date or timestamp, you can embed it into the assembly when building.
For how to do that, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971476/how-do-i-find-the-current-time-and-date-at-compilation-time-in-net-c-applicatio/971663#971663).